# JS Regex for a string contains fixed number of letters

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I need to have minimum 5 letters in a string not requiring that they are subsequent. The regex below checks subsequent letters

```
[A-Za-z]{5,}
```

So, *"aaaaa"* -- **true**, but *"aaa1aa"* -- **false**.

What is the regex to leave the sequence condition, that **both** of the strings above would pass as true.

Comment: Maybe `[A-Za-z0-9]{5,}` would be enough

Comment: Clarification: aaa1a should not pass!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove all non-letter chars with `.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '')` and then run the regex:

```js
var strs = ["aaaaa", "aaa1aa"];
var val_rx = /[a-zA-Z]{5,}/;
for (var s of strs) { 
  console.log( val_rx.test(s.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '')) );
}
```

Else, you may also use a one step solution like

```js
var strs = ["aaaaa", "aaa1aa"];
var val_rx = /(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){5,}/;
for (var s of strs) { 
  console.log( s, "=>", val_rx.test(s) );
}
```

See this [second regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/0qVcKD/1). `(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){5,}` matches 5 or more consecutive occurrences of 0 or more non-letter chars (`[^a-zA-Z]*`) followed with a letter char.

Answer (score 1):

Allow non-letter characters between the letters:

```
(?:[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*){5,}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use a regular expression only, here's one somewhat ugly option:

```js
const check = str => /^(.*[A-Za-z].*){5}/.test(str);
console.log(check("aaaaa"));
console.log(check("aa1aaa"));
console.log(check("aa1aa"));
```

Answer (score 1):

w means alphanumeric in regex,
it will be ok : \w{5,}

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}
```

Just like this? Or do you mean it needs to be a regex that ignores digits? Because the above would match `aaaa1` as well.